# Xamarin Forms Deserialise Json Not Working

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having issues deserialising a json package.

I tried copying the examples online but can't seem to extract the total price even tho the code executes fine.

I simply want to extract the total price from my json package here:

```
{"rates":[{"service_name":"FastDelivery","service_code":"FD","total_price":7.150}],"success":true}
```

Here's my code:

```
Rate response_variables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rate>(response_package);

var response_field = response_variables.total_price;

Console.WriteLine("Shipping Price:");

Console.WriteLine(response_field);
```

And my public class Rate

```
public class Rate
        {
            public string service_name { get; set; }
            public string service_code { get; set; }
            public double total_price { get; set; }

        }
```

Am I missing anything? Or is there another way I can extract the total_price?

Comment: Your class structure does not match the json. Copy the json, in Visual Studio open a new file, go to Edit > Paste special > Paste json as classes. Then, change Type names as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Crowcoder said, the class you're desirializing is not a "Rate" object, it's a class that contains a list of Rate objects and a boolean.

I suggest you to check the model you need to use for your JSON in https://json2csharp.com/.

In this case, the JSON you're trying to read deserializes as:

```
public class Rate    {
    public string service_name { get; set; } 
    public string service_code { get; set; } 
    public double total_price { get; set; } 

}

public class Root    {
    public List<Rate> rates { get; set; } 
    public bool success { get; set; } 

}
```

Whereas "Root" is the class that is going to contain the element that you're trying to read.

To extract the total price you'll have to access to every Rate with a loop:

```
Root response_variables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root> (response_package);
foreach(var rate in response_variables.rates){
var price = rate.total_price;
//Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Oscar, much appreciated! It's now working! :)